# AngularJS watcher not binding/ watching

Tags: angularjs, bind, target

I'm trying to implement the "infinite-scroll" feature in a list using a directive, which should load progressively a new set of "orders" when the scroll of the html element reaches or exceeds 75% of the scrollable height and append it to the existing list.
Unfortunately, the watcher doesn't trigger when i scroll the list. 
The directive is located in the right tag and the watcher triggers the listener function only the first time, when the element is rendered by the browser.
The strange thing is that if i change path and then i return to the path where the list is, the watcher start behaving correctly and trigger the listener function everytime i perform a scroll.

```
<ol orders-loader class="orders-list">...</ol>
```

angular:

```
(function () {
angular.
        module('myApp')
        .directive('ordersLoader', ['$window', '$timeout', 'ordersResource', ordersloaderDirective])

function ordersloaderDirective($window, $timeout, loading, ordersResource) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.orders = ordersResource; /*ordersResource use $resource to api calls
            and then stocks the data in a array exposed in the scope*/

            $timeout(function () {
                scope.$watch(function () { return element[0].scrollTop }, function () {
                    if (*the scroll exceedes more or less 75% of the total scrollHeight*/) {
                            /*asking for more orders*/                            
                    }
                });
            }, 0);
        }

    }
}
```

I can't figure out where is the problem.

**Solved**
As ***yeouuu*** suggested, there was no digest cycle after the list scroll event, so i added:

```
element.bind('scroll', function () {
                scope.$apply();
            });
```

just before the $timeout function.

Comment: What's listening to the scroll action? There is probably no digest cycle after scrolling?

Comment: How is it possible? The $watch service should monitor if some scope element has changed on every digest cycle or am I missing something?

Comment: If the value you're watching changes outside angular. For example in a jQuery plugin, then the watcher doesn't know.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i solved my problem following your suggestion. I'll update my question adding the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever using plugins outside of angularJs that should trigger watcher you need to explicitly apply them. Otherwise Angular won't be aware of these changes/events.

In your case that means adding `scope.$apply();` after the event.

**Your edited solution:**

```
element.bind('scroll', function () {
  scope.$apply();
});
```

More information can be found here about the scope life cycle: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-life-cycle